# Does MSI file support CRC checks on Windows?

Tags: windows-installer, crc, crc32

I was curious if it's possible to tell if the MSI file was modified since it was built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not in the manner you are expecting, but if you always sign your MSI files any modifications after they have been signed will invalidate the digital signature.

Signing an MSI is always a good idea, as the UAC prompt for an unsigned MSI is different than for one with a valid digital signature.

For more information refer to MSDN - [How to: Sign Setup Files with SignTool.exe (Windows Installer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290833.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. On the side note, I was wondering if it's possible to run this signtool from a command line (w/o user interaction)?

Comment: @ahmd0 This signtool runs _only_ on command line, it's not a GUI application.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov versions prior to .NET4/VS2010 include the "signwizard" command line option to launch an interactive GUI, but yes as of the current version you are correct.

Comment: @saschabeaumont I haven't known about it since I've never used .NET. However I used signtool to sign executables, and it was command line utility.

Comment: I've never used .NET either ;) That was just the largest change to the Windows SDK when they dropped the wizard option - I'm still using an old version from the Platform SDK ... *whoops!*